# What amount of resources do you get back for aborting a currently building damaged building?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-de

If someone damages a building that is currently being built, and you cancel it say at 1% health, do you get back full resources? I know aborting a building that isn't damaged gives back full resources, but what about damaged ones?

Answer (score 4):

IIRC, you get the "non-built" amount back when you cancel.
So if your castle is 80% built, you'll get 20% of its cost refunded IF YOU CANCEL.

A foundation destroyed by enemies will lose all of its resources even if it was only 1% complete, though it cannot actually be seen/targeted until one of your villagers has started working on it.

I don't think the damage the building incurred has any impact on the refund as long as it isn't destroyed.